# Unable to reach Expo servers. Cannot Load app onto Phone or simulator when developing in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

When loading up my app it says in the command prompt:

> Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.

I can still access the metro bundler and load the app in the web browser.

However, I cannot load the app onto a simulator or load it onto my phone using the QR code. It was working before.

When attempting to load on simulator/phone an error pops up:

> Error: read ECONNRESET
> at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)

and this will show on my phone:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYolS.jpg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

i think thats because you forget your vpn on ?
because i solve my problem when i turned off my vpn

Answer (score -1):

I had the fowllowing error message:

```html
Unable to reach Expo servers. Falling back to using the cached dependency map (bundledNativeModules.json) from the package "expo" installed in your project.
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6812:568:443
FetchError: request to https://api.expo.dev/v2/versions/latest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6812:568:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nguye\Documents\FE_MOBILE_DACN\FE_MOBILE_DACN\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1491:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

After a lot of searching, I turned off the network and reconnected and the program worked, you can try